# URI Permissions

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-file, android-contentresolver

So the problem I got is, that I want the user to pick an `xml` file using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, which configures the application, but after a restart of the application I don't have the `URI` permission anymore and it crashes.

I could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and persist the `URI` permission. But with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` the file that I want to access is no longer shown in the file picker.

This is ridiculous, I just want to open a file, that the user picked himself! Picking the `xml` file after every restart of the app is not an option.

```
public void onChooseFileButtonClicked(View view) {
    Intent fileIntentSicherung;

    fileIntentSicherung = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    fileIntentSicherung.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    //fileIntentSicherung.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);

    //fileIntentSicherung.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    fileIntentSicherung.setType("text/xml");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(fileIntentSicherung, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file will be stored in the root directory, that is shown when connecting via usb to a pc.

With `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`:

[image: ACTION_GET_CONTENT]

With `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`:

[image: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT]

Comment: "after a restart of the application i don't have the uri permission anymore and it crashes" -- correct. "But with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT the file that i want to access is no longer shown in the file picker" -- the user can tap the overflow menu and choose "Show internal storage", which may enable the location that you are seeking. Beyond all of that, what is your question?

Comment: Please give an example of a file path that you can reach with action get content and not with the other one.

Comment: `and it crashes.` Your app should not crash if you catch some exceptions.

Comment: or throws exception, i meant that by saying it crashes. I don't know why the screenshots are not showing, take a look here: 
https://imgur.com/qi9omhV
https://imgur.com/ZyJ8T8r

The first picture shows the option "Dateien" or "Files" in english, the second one using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT doesn't even have this option. This is on a Huawei Device running Android 7.0.

Comment: I think the type: `.setType("text/xml");` should be `.setType("text/xml/*");`.  `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` usable for Android 4.4 and higher versions. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_PICK` - Android 4.3 and lower. Make sure you selected the right flag.

Comment: There are two blue icons in every screen. Click on the right one to open a menu.

Comment: Try with `setType("*/*");` first.

Comment: But i'd like it to only show xml files, isn't that the whole point about the type?

Comment: @RicoChr. I have the same problem. Do you find any solution to give permanent acces to Uri from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`